# How allow naming test files like testee.test.py with pytest?

Tags: python, pytest

Given a class lets say `Car`, I would like to name the corresponding test file `car.test.py`.

So, in `pytest.ini` I set `python_files = *.test.py`.
But then, when running pytest, I get the following:

```
ImportError while importing test module '/..../tests/car.test.py'.
Hint: make sure your test modules/packages have valid Python names.
```

I had a unused `__init__` file in the test root, deleted that.

Also cleared cache after renaming my tests.
Anything else I can try? Is this even possible?

Comment: There is no easy way to import a python module that has a `.` in it

Comment: where is the problem with calling it `test_car.py`

Comment: @mousetail in this case it not a module as I understand the concept, but maybe it does not matter?

Comment: It's still a module, just imported by pytest

Comment: @dosas It blends the testee name with metadata Id rather separate it if possible

Comment: test_testtee.py?

Comment: @dosas Yes I don't like that and hence the question. I have a hard time reading it fast and separate the parts in my slow brain. Especially since class name parts are also snake case they blend IMO. Anyhow I would consider the liking or not to be off topic, question is if it possible to use name.test.py syntax. Thanks though for questioning this :)